# In PHP, make every letter left of colon lowercase w/o use of explode,implode

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Can this be done with regular expressions?

Examples

x-example-HEADER:teSt
becomes
x-example-header:teSt

y-exaMPLE:testoneTWOthree
becomes
y-example:testoneTWOthree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`e` modifier](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) on a regular expression pattern when given to [`preg_replace`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (take a look at example #4 on that page) in order to call PHP code as part of the replacement:

```
$string = "x-example-HEADER:teSt";
$new_string = preg_replace('/(^.+)(?=:)/e', "strtolower('\\1')", $string);
// => x-example-header:teSt
```

The pattern will grab everything before the first colon into the first backreference, and then replace it with the `strtolower` function.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$output = preg_replace_callback('![a-zA-Z]+:!', 'to_lower', $input);

function to_lower($matches) {
  return strtolower($matches[0]);
}
```

You can't otherwise do case conversion with regular expressions except in specific cases (eg replace 'A' with 'a' is possible).

**Edit:** Ok, you learn something new everyday. You can do this:

```
$output = preg_replace('![a-zA-Z]+:!e', "strtoupper('\\1')", $input);
```

From [Pattern Modifiers](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> ***e*** (PREG_REPLACE_EVAL)
>
> If this modifier is set,
>   [preg_replace()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) does normal
>   substitution of backreferences in the
>   replacement string, evaluates it as
>   PHP code, and uses the result for
>   replacing the search string. Single
>   quotes, double quotes, backslashes ()
>   and NULL chars will be escaped by
>   backslashes in substituted
>   backreferences.
>
> Only [preg_replace()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) uses this
>   modifier; it is ignored by other PCRE
>   functions.

I would however shy away from eval()ing strings, especially when combined with user input it can be a *very* dangerous practice. I would prefer the `preg_replace_callback()` approach as a general rule.

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'y-exaMPLE:testoneTWOthree';
function lower( $str ) {
    return strtolower( $str[1] );
}

echo preg_replace_callback( '~^([^:]+)~', 'lower', $str );
```